# indexPathForCell returns nil since ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

my app was running fine under ios6.1. tried the ios7 simulator and the following part does not work:

```
EditingCell *cell = (EditingCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"the section is %d and row is %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *rowKey = [[keysForRows objectAtIndex: section] objectAtIndex: row];
```

It always comes:

```
the section is 0 and row is 0
```

although another section / row were selected. 
Has someone an idea why this does not work under ios7?

Comment: Have you verified that textfield.superview.superview isKindOfClass EditingCell? The view hierarchy for the cell may have changed.

Comment: `[[textField superview] superview]` is pretty bad way to reference anything.

Comment: I got the app like it is.. and wants to bring it run under iOS 7.

Comment: how can i verify if editing cell iskindofclass? (i am very new on the ios developing..)

Comment: to find out what the class your cell is, try `NSLog(@"Class of Cell: %@", NSStringFromClass(cell.class));` You also might want to look into the UITableView-Method ìndexPathOfSelectedCell`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Class of Cell: UITableViewCellScrollView

Comment: Go one more `superview` then, if you can't create a better reference.

Comment: looks that with one more superview it works. have to test it. but do you have an idea why it works under iOS 6 and not under ios7? And what would be the better way?

Comment: It seems that it is now running under ios7. now if i want to run under ios6.1 simulator it comes: build successfully and than ios simulation failed to install the application. idea?

Comment: Because they change the view hierarchy without notice so getting objects like that is very unreliable. Can't say much with the given code but it looks like you could subclass the `UITextField` and keep the `NSIndexPath` as it's property.

Comment: An idea why now iOS Simulator failed to install the application
comes??

Comment: the running problem solved..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your approach to find the "enclosing" table view cell of a text field is fragile,
because is assumes a fixed view hierarchy (which seems to have changed between
iOS 6 and iOS 7).

One possible solution would be to traverse up in the view hierarchy until the table view cell is found:

```
UIView *view = textField;
while (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    view = [view superview];
}
EditingCell *cell = (EditingCell *)view;
```

A completely different, but often used method is to "tag" the text field with the row
number:

```
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;   // in cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

and then just use that tag in the text field delegate methods.

Comment: Nice, this works ( first solution). Is there anything to care? or is this the normal (or one normal) way?

Comment: There is a case where using tag might not work. If you have code that peforms -insertRowsAtIndexPaths on the table view, the tags will not match the indexPath.row.

Comment: @PaulHeller: It should match on all *visible* cells, because it is always updated in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but you are right, your objection makes the tag method look fragile as well.

Comment: If the row scrolls out of view, superview can return nil and leave you in an infinite loop

Comment: @BradThomas: I had assumed that in the delegate/action method of a control inside the cell the cell would be visible. But you never know, and adding a check for a nil superview should definitely be done (added to the answer). Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR, you are welcome. In my case I discovered this inside textFieldDidEndEditing, which by the way seems to get handled differently in iOS6 and iOS7 when the containing cell has been deallocated (e.g. by not being visible). In my case I discovered that while iOS6 was being forgiving of the cell reuse identifier not being specified in the NIB, iOS7 was less so. My conclusion is that getting into a situation where one of the containing view(s) is nil is possible if the there are design flaws in the code. I'm less clear if it's possible to get into that situation with well designed code.

Answer (score 22):

I was finding cells the same way you were. Now I use this quick method if I have a button in a cell and know the tableview I'm in. It'll return the tableviewcell.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)GetCellFromTableView:(UITableView*)tableView Sender:(id)sender {
    CGPoint pos = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pos];
    return [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: this should definitely be the answer. The less one relay on views hierarchy the better.

Comment: Works greatly when indexPathForCell returns nil for whatever reason. Verified on iOS 8

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this problem in iOS 11, but not in 9 or 10, I overrode the `func indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath?` method using the technique that @drexel-sharp detailed previously:

```
override func indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath? {
    var indexPath = super.indexPath(for: cell)
    if indexPath == nil { // TODO: iOS 11 Bug?
        let point = cell.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self)
        indexPath = indexPathForRow(at: point)
    }
    return indexPath
}
```