# indexPathForCell returning NULL under IOS 7, works fine under IOS 6

Tags: uitableview, ios6, ios7

I'm hoping now apps for IOS 7 are being accepted by Apple we can talk about it?

I'm trying to fix my app so it works on IOS 7 and have made some very good progress this evening. I have two outstanding issues, but will post them separately. The first issue is this line (I added a log line after to debug it)  ...

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [settingsTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];
 NSLog(@"Changed %@ <-**-> %@", [sender superview], indexPath );
```

The log shows ....

**IOS7**

```
 2013-09-11 22:18:02.985 BusTimes[21013:a0b] Changed <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbfc1c80; frame =  (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbfc1e70>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbfc1540>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> <-**-> (null)

 2013-09-11 22:18:08.577 BusTimes[21013:a0b] Changed <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbfc62d0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbfc64c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbfc5b90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> <-**-> (null)
```

**IOS 6**

```
2013-09-11 22:25:34.495 BusTimes[2116:907] Changed <UITableViewCell: 0x20862f40; frame = (0 179; 320 44); text = 'Reminder Mins: 5'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x208523d0>> <-**-> <NSIndexPath 0x20861430> 2 indexes [0, 3]
2013-09-11 22:25:47.499 BusTimes[2116:907] Changed <UITableViewCell: 0x20865180; frame = (0 223; 320 44); text = 'AutoRefresh Secs: 60'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x20865340>> <-**-> <NSIndexPath 0x2085c0d0> 2 indexes [0, 4]
```

So on IOS 7 indexPath is always (null) and .section and .row are always 0. But this works fine on IOS 6 and returns .section 0 and row 3, and .row 4. Can anyone suggest how I might get IOS 7 to behave in the same way for me?

Many Thanks in advance.

Plasma

*** SOLUTION - I changed my code to this following the comments ***

```
UIView *view = sender;

while (![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    view = [view superview];
}

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [settingsTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];
```

Comment: This answer should help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18743747/1838805

Comment: Magic, I've manged to fix that, now time to investigate the other issue. Text input pop up box on IOS 7 downt work! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [indexPathForCell returns nil since ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7)

Comment: Does this because the view hierarchy has changed in iOS 7.

Comment: Wow that saved me alot of time . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's usually safer to make no assumptions about the view hierarchy of a cell. In the past, I've used a category with methods like this on UIView to find the superview which is a cell:

```
- (UIView*)ancestorOrSelfWithClass:(Class)cls {
  if ([self isKindOfClass:cls]) {
    return self;

  } else if (self.superview) {
    return [self.superview ancestorOrSelfWithClass:cls];

  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```

So you'll ask for `[sender ancestorOrSelfWithClass:[UITableViewCell class]]` to get the actual cell, and it'll work no matter what hierarchy exists within the cell.