# Tableview button get index.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I got a button in a tableview cell (named "deleteTemplate"), and when it's pressed i should get the "index.row" for the cell the button is in. Anybody knows how to get the "index.row" for the cell, when you click a button in the cell?

My current code for the button:

```
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

NSDictionary *dic = [tableData objectAtIndex:clickedButtonIndexPath.row];
```

But clickedButtonIndexPath = NULL? :(

This worked in iOS 6.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Where is this being called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [indexPathForCell returns nil since ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7)

Comment: Did you try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751658/indexpathforcell-returning-null-under-ios-7-works-fine-under-ios-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting null because the view hierarchy in iOS 7 is changed.

I recommend to use Delegate for getting the indexpath of TableViewCell.

[You can get the sample project from here](http://ideamakerz.com/mzeeshanid/how-to-get-the-index-for-the-cell-when-you-click-a-button-in-the-cell/)

Here is the sample:

My View Controller looks like this:

```
//#import "ViewController.h"
//#import "MyCustomCell.h"
@interface ViewController () 
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    NSMutableArray *dataSourceArray;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dataSourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        [dataSourceArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dummy-%d",i]];
}
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
//pragma mark - UITableView Delegate And Datasource -
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return dataSourceArray.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdenfifier = @"MyCustomCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdenfifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setDelegate:self];
    [cell.myButton setTitle:[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
//pragma mark - MyCustomCell Delegate -
-(IBAction)myCustomCellButtonTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell button:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexpath: %@",indexPath);
}
@end
```

MyCustomCell.h looks like this:

```
//#import 
@protocol MyCustomCellDelegate 
@optional
- (IBAction)myCustomCellButtonTapped:(UITableViewCell *)cell button:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@property(nonatomic, weak)id delegate;
@end
```

MyCustomCell.m looks like this:

```
//#import "MyCustomCell.h"
@implementation MyCustomCell
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
//#pragma mark - My IBActions -
-(IBAction)myCustomCellButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myCustomCellButtonTapped:button:)])
        [self.delegate myCustomCellButtonTapped:self button:sender];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

you set tag for your button in **cellforrowatindexpath**

```
clickedButtonIndexPath.tag=indexpath.row;
```

when button is presse in action write

```
nslog(@"%i",btutton.tag);
```

if clickedbuttonindexpath is nil it wont uitableviewcell

Comment: The question is why is `clickedIndexPath` coming back as `nil`. This has nothing to do with setting the button's tag. Besides, setting a button's tag to the `indexPath.row` is not the best solution since rows can be added, removed, or reordered.

Comment: can you please print clickedCell in nslog .i think it wont be uitableviewcell it will be view

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered many times. For completion, here is the best solution:

```
    -(IBAction)cellButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        CGRect buttonFrame = [sender convertRect:sender.bounds toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrame.origin];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you make the cell assign at you `button.tag` the `indexPath.row` and when you click the button in your  method you have the sender (the button) and you get the indexPath from the sender's tag

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And this solution doesn't work if rows can be added, removed, or reordered.