# Not returning the cell of a particular table in ios7

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi in my application I am facing one issue that is the below code not returing the cell in ios7. Can you please let me know the reason. Actually i have button on cell when ever i click that button that particular cell have to return.

(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]

Comment: possible duplicate of [indexPathForCell returns nil since ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and use button tag to solve this issue as below.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableviewObject indexPathForRowAtPoint:yourbutton.tag];
return [tableviewObject cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```