# accessing my custom cell in a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I have a tableview that is built like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    PhotoSummaryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *photoCaption = [[[self.form valueForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"caption" ];

    cell.textfieldCaption.text = photoCaption;
    cell.textfieldCaption.tag=indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

What I want to do is get the index of the textfield that was edited? I wired up the textfield in the custom cell and made an action that executes on ending an edit:

```
- (IBAction)getIndexForCaption:(id)sender {

[[[self.form valueForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:cell.textfieldCaption.tag] setObject:cell.textfieldCaption.text forKey:@"caption"];

}
```

But how this is now, I dont have the "cell" so I get undeclared identifier "cell" error. How can I get the custom cell in this case?

Comment: Assuming `sender` is the `UITextField` in the cell, walk up the `superview` from the text field until you get the table view cell.

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7 show different approaches to find the "enclosing" table view cell.

Comment: FYI - be careful using `indexPath.row` as a tag. This only works if the rows of the table can't be inserted (other than at the end), removed, or reordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options available to do this. Personally, I would prefer make a subclass of UITextField with an extra property for the `PhotoSummaryCell`. You could set this property when the cell gets recycled, and this would make getting the index of the text field as easy as:

```
NSIndexPath *indexOfTextField = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:textField.cell];
```

Then of course, you could step through the text fields view hierarchy until you find a cell, or save the index path's row into the textfields `tag` property as @rmaddy and @Martin R pointed out.

Make sure that you declare your `cell` property as `weak` to avoid retain cycle.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. I need to make another class? then what?

Comment: @BluGeni Yes, you make another class that is a subclass of UITextField. Then you add a custom property to that text field for the cell (weakly referenced). Then you replace the current text field on your cell with this new subclass. When the cell gets reused (cellForRow...) you set that current cell to the cell property of the text field. You can now reference the cell like by accessing it directly from the text field ex `textField.cell`.