# How to get UIPickerView value in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView on each row of my UITableViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 CartCell *cell = (CartCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CartCell"];
    Cart *cart = (self.carts)[indexPath.row];
   cell.productnameLabel.text = cart.productname;
   cell.priceLabel.text = cart.price;

 picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 100, 40)];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    arrayColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Red"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Orange"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Yellow"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Green"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Blue"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Indigo"];
[arrayColors addObject:@"Violet"];

    [cell addSubview:picker];

return cell;
}
```

and I have the didSelectRow for the picker

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [arrayColors objectAtIndex:row], row);
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
         NSLog(@"indexPathForSelectedRow  %@", path);

}
```

But I am getting the path vaue as null.
How to get UIPickerView value in UITableView. I need the picker value of each row.

Comment: what you want ,why you create each cell UIPickerView and NSMutableArray ?

Comment: I am listing shopping cart in this table. And I want to update the quantity(or Color) of the product in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[thePickerView superview];
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"indexPathForSelectedRow  %@", path);
```

Comment: null returns for indexPathForCell also. Is it because custom cell?

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention about my sdk version. it is ios. and I got the solution from this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7

Comment: and modified code  - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    UIView *view = thePickerView;
    while (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        view = [view superview];
    }
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;
    
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexPathForSelectedRow  %@", path);
    NSLog(@"the section is %d and row is %d", path.section, path.row);
    }

Comment: hmn... all is good and it would be better if you use CartCell in place of UITableViewCell. In line
while (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])

Comment: I have tried CartCell *cell = (CartCell *)[thePickerView superview]; but same null result came. But it worked with UIView while loops. Not sure why it is not working with CartCell.

Comment: This works . after UIView while loop   " CartCell *cell = (CartCell *)view;" and this also helped me to change other cell values. For example:   cell.quantityLabel.text =[arrayColors objectAtIndex:row];