# After reloading UITableView data, indexPathForCell returns null

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, uirefreshcontrol

I have a UITableView in a ViewController which contains a custom cell.
When the view first loads, the indexPathForCell in the following code returns the indexPath without problems:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCell"];

    if (postCell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"EmptyCell Found");
    }

    NSDictionary *object = [postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *imageURL = [object objectForKey:@"imageURL"];

    NSIndexPath *originalIndexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"Original IndexPath %@", originalIndexPath);

    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                         options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0
                        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){}
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished){
                           if (image) {

                               // This returns correctly on first load
                               NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [imageTableView indexPathForCell:postCell];
                               NSLog(@"Current IndexPath %@", currentIndexPath);
                           }
                       }
        ];
}
```

After refreshing the tableView, currentIndexPath is always (null).
The following is my refresh code:

```
- (void)refreshMainView {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadPostOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:serviceRequest];

    [downloadPostOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //[tableView beginUpdates];

        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *newPostArray = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];

        // Replacing the old array with new array
        postArray = newPostArray;    
        [self stopRefresh];        
        //[tableView endUpdates]
        [imageTableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self stopRefresh];
    }];
```

If I just perform [tableView reloadData] without performing refreshMainView, there will not be any problem with getting the currentIndexPath.

There must be something I am overlooking, could someone please help me? Thank you!

Edit:
I have tried `[postCell.postImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:nil];` instead and the refreshing works, so I am suspecting that something is wrong with me getting the indexPath in the completed block, can anyone help out please? I need the completed block as I am doing some image processing.

Comment: Calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` in your completion block is unnecessary as you don't insert or remove cells.

Comment: might be it happens because of `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` Block that refresh your table view before fill post Array.

Comment: Hi Nitin, could you elaborate? I have tried using `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` but it does not help.

According to [link](http://nscookbook.com/2013/12/ios-programming-recipe-16-2-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web-ios-7-and-afnetworking-2-0/) the reload is also within the completionBlock.

Comment: Where do imageURL, postData, newPostArray variables come from ? Please show more code.

Comment: @HoanNguyen hi, I have updated with more code.

Comment: In CellForIndext: I found a imageTableView and in refreshMainView ([imageTableView indexPathForCell:postCell]), I found an other tableview ([tableView reloadData]) ? Are you having two tableview?

Comment: @HoanNguyen No sorry it is a typo, I have updated my code. I only have one tableView in the storyboard.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743099/indexpathforcell-returns-nil-since-ios7, maybe it help

Comment: Hi @HoanNguyen the link does not help me. Some more information, I find it weird that `[imageTableView visibleCells]` does not show my cell as visible when I can see it. When I check the postCell, it has `hidden = YES;` when it is on screen. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Hello anyone can help me on this issue? I think I may not be calling the `indexPathForCell` correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I have finally fixed it.

For people who are needing answers, just add

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`
`});`

around the portion that is retrieving the indexPathForCell.

Comment: how can this happen on earth?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCell"];


    if (cell == nil)
        {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostCell" owner:self options:nil];
}
    NSIndexPath *originalIndexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"Original IndexPath %@", originalIndexPath);
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                     options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0
                    progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){}
                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished){
                       if (image) {

                           // This returns correctly on first load
                           NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [imageTableView indexPathForCell:postCell];
                           NSLog(@"Current IndexPath %@", currentIndexPath);
                       }
                   }
    ];
```

use this it may help you

Comment: Hello actually I am already checking for nil cell with `if (postCell == nil)` but it does not catch anything. And I'm using storyboard so I do not have a nib. I have updated my question.

Comment: use the break point and check is there any reference in the postCell

Comment: hi, I have updated my post: I am not able to get the currentIndexPath in the completed block after I refresh the tableView, I'm not sure why this is happening as I can get it before the refresh. Any help? - btw the postCell has a reference, just that imageTableView indexPathForCell: returns (null)